# Will killing a petrified drow give me XP?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

My party encountered some Drows in the Underdark (X: 130 Y: -238). We then fought a Spectator who revived a few of the Drows during combat. We talked to the leader of the Drows who made all the revived Drows attack us.

After the fight, we noticed two Drows were still petrified. We un-petrified one, only for it to immediately attack us. After killing it and getting XP, only one petrified Drow remains.

If we kill the petrified Drow without un-petrifying it, will we get XP?

[image: Petrified drow that I can attack]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not gain any experience points from killing them, nor will you affect your reputation with any faction or character.

Comment: They have a bit of loot however.